# sending discord notification if changes in bash output (will be put in a cron)

Tags: bash, notify-send, discord

I need to recieve a discord notification if this command does not have the string "No differences discovered" in the last 2 lines of the output. Ive been at it for hours I dont get it! and NO i do not know what amass says if there is a difference.

```
amass track -d beesy.me | grep "No differences discovered"

    if [[$? -eq 1]];  
        discord_notify "Changes in beesy.me domain!"
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is likely not putting spaces as follows `[[ $1 -eq 1 ]];`

You could also just use the || operator.

```
amass track -d beesy.me | grep -q "No differences discovered" || \
        discord_notify "Changes in beesy.me domain!"
```